# The linear-gradient hack for tinted images: Am I doing it wrong?

Tags: html, css

Was reading how to do it on https://css-tricks.com/tinted-images-multiple-backgrounds/

```
/* Working method */
.tinted-image {
  background: 
    /* top, transparent red, faked with gradient */ 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45), 
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45)
    ),
    /* bottom, image */
    url(image.jpg);
}
```

For me, though, it doesn't seem to work. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w6jnv67c/

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, what you are doing wrong is not allowing for the size of the image.

The image is placed at the top left of the div which, in this case, means that there is nothing to see in that area of the image.

Just make the div a little larger and you will see.

```css
.tinted-image {
  background:
  /* top, transparent red, faked with gradient */
  linear-gradient(rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45)),
  /* bottom, image */
  url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a);
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tinted-image">

</div>
```

So if you want the image to fit in the div you have to use `background-size`.

```css
.tinted-image {
  background:
  /* top, transparent red, faked with gradient */
  linear-gradient(rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45)),
  /* bottom, image */
  url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="tinted-image">

</div>
```